# tint() on createGraphics() buffer in p5

Tags: rendering, processing, p5.js, tint, pgraphics

I'm trying to change the opacity of an offscreen graphics buffer in p5, and can't figure it out.

consider:

```js
var pg = createGraphics(...)
var image = loadImage(...)

tint(255, 50)
image(image, 0, 0) <----- this works
image(pg, 0, 0)    <----- but this doesn't
```

[working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/defenestrated/zc03gm3g/26/)

`tint(255, x)` *should* leave the coloring unchanged and set the opacity to `x`, but seems to have no effect. works fine on images, though... what am I missing?

Comment: This is a great question. I'd expect `tint()` to work on graphics as well. It works exactly how we're expecting in regular Processing. I did find [this related bug](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/1181) that's talking about the canvas. You might consider filing a bug of your own. (If you're not familiar with GitHub, I can do that for you if you want. Just let me know.)

Comment: @KevinWorkman That's an interesting bug, but still dealing with images rather than rendering contexts themselves... I can definitely file a new bug, but I want to be sure that it's _actually_ a bug, and not instead a problem of documentation – I found a workaround that I'll add below, which might help clarify things

Comment: Honestly I would still file a bug. Worst case scenario we get confirmation from a developer that this is the intended behavior.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** It seems as though in P5 (though not in Processing), tint() *does* in fact work only on `p5.Image` objects. So, a workaround is to create a `p5.Image` from the offscreen graphics buffer using `get()` to grab pixels from the buffer (which returns an image). Confusingly, the reference article for `get()` also uses images, making it hard to understand what's actually happening.

An updated (working) example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/defenestrated/zc03gm3g/32/).

To reiterate, the reason this is worth doing at all is to render complex shapes (like text) only *once* to a buffer, then draw / manipulate that buffer as needed. This drastically reduces CPU load and speeds up the sketch.

(credit for figuring this out goes to [Ian](https://github.com/iaaaan))

Comment: @KevinWorkman see what I mean about the bug? It's not... _broken_, per se, just confusing, because the way you render a graphics buffer is with `image()`, implying that the same methods that work on `Image` objects should also work on `p5.Renderer` objects... what do you think?